# tkinter widget not showing up

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

I just started learning python and tkinter earlier today and I cannot get any widgets to show up in the window.  It has the name I gave it and the window itself shows up when I run the program, but no widgets appear, nor does the background color.

```
import Tkinter

class mainthing(Tkinter.Tk):
   def _init_(self,parent):
      Tkinter.Tk.__init__(self,parent)
      self.parent = parent
      self.initialize()

   def initialize(self):
      self.grid(bg="#001a00")

      self.topEntry = Tkinter.Entry(self, bg = "#006600", fg = "#00ff00")
      self.topEntry.grid(column=0, row=1, sticky="EW")
      topEntry.pack()

      yesBut = Tkinter.Button(self, text="Yes")
      yesBut.grid(column=1, row=1)

      query = Tkinter.Label(self, fg="#00ff00", bg="#001a00", anchor="W")
      query.grid(column=1, row=0, columnspan=2, sticky="EW")

if __name__ == "__main__":   
   app = mainthing(None)
   app.title("RUN ON START TEST")
   app.mainloop()
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: *I just started learning Python and tkinter earlier today*: That is why your *code* is a ***BIG MESS***. It is too early for you to ask a question here. IYou can find an answer on any [beginner tutorial](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/tkinter-index.htm). Please visit the [Help Center](http://stackoverflow.com/help)

Answer (score 2):

> I just started learning Python and tkinter earlier today

I think it is too early for you to post questions on here as you need to read more about Python and Tkinter. Your question may be closed, however I will give you a solution with a short description of your errors:

- First of all, you have a typo: we write `__init__()` and not `_init()_`
- You need to pass `Frame` instead of `Tk` in `class mainthing(Tkinter.Tk)`
- Change `Tkinter.Tk.__init__(self, parent)` to `Tkinter.Frame.__init__(self, parent)`
- This has no sense: `self.grid(bg="#001a00")`. Remove it.
- Your widgets are not visible because you need to attach them to a `Canvas` or a `Frame`.
- Think twice about your main application.
- Do not mix `pack()` and `grid()`.

Here is a quick solution using `Frame`:

```
import Tkinter as Tk

class mainthing(Tk.Frame):
   def __init__(self,parent):
      Tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
      self.parent = parent
      self.initialize()

   def initialize(self):

      self.parent.title("RUN ON START TEST")       
      self.parent.grid_rowconfigure(0,weight=1)
      self.parent.grid_columnconfigure(0,weight=1)
      self.parent.config(background="red") 

      self.frame = Tk.Frame(self.parent)  
      self.frame.pack(fill=Tk.X, padx=5, pady=5)

      self.topEntry = Tk.Entry(self.frame, bg = "#006600", fg = "#00ff00")
      self.topEntry.grid(column=0, row=1, sticky="ew")


      yesBut = Tk.Button(self.frame, text="Yes")
      yesBut.grid(column=1, row=1)

      query = Tk.Label(self.frame, fg="#00ff00", bg="#001a00", anchor="w")
      query.grid(column=1, row=0, columnspan=2, sticky="ew")


if __name__ == "__main__": 
   root=Tk.Tk()
   app = mainthing(root)   
   root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 2):

There are some smaller mistakes:

1. it should read `__init__`, with two underscores
2. Background is set with `config``
3. `topEntry.pack` is unnecessary, since you use `grid`

With these corrections, the code look like this:

```
import Tkinter

class mainthing(Tkinter.Tk):
   def __init__(self,parent):
      Tkinter.Tk.__init__(self,parent)
      self.parent = parent
      self.initialize()

   def initialize(self):
      self.config(bg="#001a00")

      self.topEntry = Tkinter.Entry(self, bg = "#006600", fg = "#00ff00")
      self.topEntry.grid(column=0, row=1, sticky="EW")

      yesBut = Tkinter.Button(self, text="Yes")
      yesBut.grid(column=1, row=1)

      query = Tkinter.Label(self, fg="#00ff00", bg="#001a00", anchor="w")
      query.grid(column=1, row=0, columnspan=2, sticky="EW")

if __name__ == "__main__":
   app = mainthing(None)
   app.title("RUN ON START TEST")
   app.mainloop()
```